# Extract foreground from individual frames using opencv for python

Tags: python, opencv

## The problem

I'm working with a camera that posts a snapshot to the web every 5 seconds or so. The camera is monitoring a line of people. I'd like my script to be able to tell me how long the line of people is.

## What I've tried

- At first, I thought I could do this using [`BackgroundSubtractorMOG`](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_video/py_bg_subtraction/py_bg_subtraction.html#backgroundsubtractormog), but this is just producing a black image. Here's my code for that, modified to use an image instead of a video capture:

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import cv2

  frame = cv2.imread('sample.jpg')
  fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()

  fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

  cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)
  cv2.waitKey()
  ```
- Next, I looked at [foreground extraction on an image](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_grabcut/py_grabcut.html), but this is interactive and doesn't suit my use case of needing the script to tell me how long the line of people is.
- I also tried to use [peopledetect.py](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/python2/peopledetect.py), but since the image of the line is from an elevated position, that script doesn't detect any people.

I'm brand new to opencv, so any help is greatly appreciated. I can supply any additional details upon request.

## Note:

I'm not so much looking for someone to solve the overall problem, as I am just trying to figure out a way to separate out the people from the background. However, I am open to approaching the problem a different way if you think you have a better solution.

**EDIT:** Here's a sample image as requested:
[image: Sample]

Comment: Can you provide a sample of what the a frame from your video looks like?  Maybe the contrast between the people and background is so poor that the background subtraction isn't doing anything useful

Comment: Cool.  I'll play around with this.  In the meantime, there are some default parameters to this method, and you're invoking these default parameters.  I'm gonna play around with the parameters to see if I get anything fruitful, but look here: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG

Comment: Awesome, I'll mess around with those as well. Thanks!

Comment: Also look here for an explanation of the parameters as well as the default: http://www.coderexception.com/CNbbzHbbPUJyXyxy/opencv-c-how-to-slow-down-background-adaptation-of-backgroundsubtractormog

Comment: Also check out `BackgroundSubtractorMOG2()`.  Apparently it's more robust: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/video/doc/motion_analysis_and_object_tracking.html#backgroundsubtractormog2

Comment: Hi, it looks like you didn't train the models! you need to train them i think: http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/video/background_subtraction/background_subtraction.html#background-subtraction

Comment: also, for approach two, face detection tends to work better than pedestrian detection, so long as they look towards the the camera! http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/py_tutorials/py_objdetect/py_face_detection/py_face_detection.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured it out! @QED helped me get there. Basically, you can't do this with just one image. You need AT LEAST 2 frames to compare so the algorithm can tell what's different (foreground) and what's the same (background). So I took 2 frames and looped through them to "train" the algorithm. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

i = 1
while(1):
  fgbg = cv2.BackgroundSubtractorMOG()
  while(i < 3):
    print 'img' + `i` + '.jpg'
    frame = cv2.imread('img' + `i` + '.jpg')

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame', fgmask)
    i += 1

    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

And here's the result from 2 consecutive images!

[image]

Comment: No worries!  I also get to learn how this works, and it's really cool to see your results!  I'm relatively new to OpenCV as well so this is something I'll keep under my hat.