# OpenCV - Fixing foreground in Background subtractor MOG

Tags: opencv, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision, feature-detection

How can we fix foreground using mog background subtractor in opencv-python? I'm trying to have a more stable foreground that can keep showing foreground once it could correctly subtract foreground from background (for example fix foreground for about 5 seconds) 
here is my code:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
history = 500   # or whatever you want it to be
accelerate = 5

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG2(history=500,  varThreshold=20,  detectShadows=True)

count=0
while(1):
    for i in (1, accelerate):
        ret, frame = cap.read()
    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame, learningRate=1.0/history)
    imageproc(fgmask,count)

#    time.sleep(5)
    k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break   
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Did you check this                                                             https://gist.github.com/lakshayg/3c23267527f3b2894398 out? It is based on https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KRKKektCcok

Comment: No, I didn't check, let me check please. that's naive subtractor, is this algorithm as well as MOG?

Comment: It just change bright objects to white and dark objects to black, what does it do?

Comment: Didn't you see it track the movements of the person under consideration? If you still want to move ahead with using MOG, I'd suggest you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24959489/extract-foreground-from-individual-frames-using-opencv-for-python and use `waitkey = 5000` if you want each frame to change after 5 seconds.

Comment: Thanks Nickil, I checked the link, it's not like my problem, I added my code, please check it. I'm trying to have a more stable foreground that can keep showing foreground once it could correctly subtract foreground from background (for example fix foreground for about 5 seconds)

Comment: This could be of some help to you:  https://www.hdm-stuttgart.de/~maucher/Python/ComputerVision/html/Tracking.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.avi')

fgbg = cv2.createBackgroundSubtractorMOG()
while(1):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    fgmask = fgbg.apply(frame)

    cv2.imshow('frame',fgmask)
    time.sleep(5)
    k = cv2.waitKey(30) & 0xff
    if k == 27:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm running this code, it does not show anything at all, but a black screen.

Comment: ops, some typo. It should be time.sleep(5)

Comment: it also returns this error: NameError: name 'sleep' is not defined

Comment: Did you import time library?

Comment: that's right.. time.sleep(5), the error is gone. but this made the output tracker sooo slow. it cannot track or show moving object clear for some seconds

Comment: Yes I imported time library, it doesn't show error enymore, but it works so slow, seems that cannot track moving object of interest.

Comment: May be you remove the sleep() and just change the value in cv2.waitKey(), which displays the image for specified milliseconds. I am not  so sure what do you mean by "show moving object clear for some seconds".

Comment: suppose that I move an object in front of webcam, at very first second mog removes background, background black and object which is moving, is now white, but I want to stop changing by moving it after the first time which I saw that white foreground.

Comment: I need to remove background and fix that obtained white region, once I saw it.

Comment: So, do you want the video pause? And it continues to record when you press a key?

Comment: Input is from webcam, I want to pause tracking and changing moving object between black and white, once I obtained object of interest which is removed from background.

Comment: If you change the cv2.waitKey() to zero, it will pause and continuous tracking if you press any button. Sorry, I have no idea how to remove the "white object". It seems that MOG will only capture the first frame.

Comment: I want to keep white object (foreground), more stable. because when I want to process it in next stage, it changes between black and white. that's the main problem. Thank you so much for your quick response.